# VideoJS player shows LIVE mode for VOD stream

Tags: video.js

I am using videoJS player with m3u8 list loaded dynamically from the server. The list has #EXT-X-ENDLIST at the end so it shouldn't be interpreted as LIVE stream. However, player shows LIVE button and the totaltime is negative.

See the screenshot:
https://adamant69-my.sharepoint.com/:i:/g/personal/tvbegovic_adamant69_onmicrosoft_com/EYPU0uKR8ypCtf9L4Z6FFAYBq1YPKDE95z5KD0lBLIHdcw?e=12C0is

The link to m3u8 list:
http://accessb.streamsink.com/hls-africa/tv1/GetVODClip.m3u8?date=2019-09-05&start=14:00:00&end=15:00:00

HTML:

```
<video-js id="wp_video1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls data-setup='{"overrideNative": true,"responsive": true}'></video-js>
```

Player is given src attribute dynamically in the code

```
player.ready(() => {
 player.src({
src: `${$scope.selectedChannel.ArchivePath}/GetVODClip.m3u8? 
  date=${mClipFrom.format('YYYY-MM-DD')}&start=${mClipFrom.format('HH:mm:ss')}&end=${mClipTo.format('HH:mm:ss')}` ,
type: 'application/x-mpegURL'
    });
});
```

Is there a problem with my m3u8 list or should I configure player differently?